# ORA-01861 on executing stored procedure from c# code

Tags: c#, sql, oracle

Below is my SP:

```
create or replace
PROCEDURE PROPORT (sValue  VARCHAR2)
AS
BEGIN

--Do some thing

END;
```

Following should execute my SP:

```
EXECUTE PROPORT('Dio');
```

the command gives runs as expected when executed directly in the SQL editor. But when the same is executed from the c# code following exception is thrown:

```
ORA-01861: literal does not match format string
ORA-06512: at "SYSADM.PROPORT", line 8
ORA-06512: at line 1
```

The command is formed using a string variable. When copied the command in the debug mode and executed in the editor, the action is performed. Please help.

Comment: Can you please post the C# code? That might give us a better idea to help you considering that you say the procedure executes successfully when invoked from SQL editor

Answer (score 0):

Your error message has to do with date string formatting. I suspect your "Do something" contains some date processing. I also suspect that you do not explicitly use a date format.
This means that the format used by the program depends on the settings that are active for the environment from which you run the code.

Use explicit date formats when programming in Oracle.